# How can we check the installed scanner driver is 32bit or 64bit on Windows 10 Professional (64 bit)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, driver, scanning

How can we check the installed scanner driver is 32bit or 64bit on Windows 10 Professional (64 bit)?

There are 3 scanners attached with my PC.
If I run TWAIN Twacker (32 bit) tool. then all 3 scanners shows in list
and If I run TWAIN Twacker (64 bit) tool then no scanners shows.

My question is, why these scanner is not showing to TWAIN Twacker (64 bit)?
Does it mean, there are only 32 bit Twain drivers installed and Twain twacker 64 bit can't read 32 bit driver devices?

**Why I need this**

  *I am working on .NET application that need to read these scanners. So when I run my application as 64 bit, it can't read these scanners and if I run my application as 32 bit then it can read all these 3.*

You can see details of  TWAIN Twacker tool from following URLs 
http://www.twain.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Twack-64.msi
https://developer.dynamsoft.com/dwt/kb/2644

I have also done testing on Windows 7 professional (64 bit) and got same results

Comment: Twain twacker 64-bit can't read 32-bit driver devices. As a workaround, you can start a 32-bit process from your 64-bit process.